# How to tear down testbed resources in Tasty conditionally?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing

I use Haskell's Tasty framework for testing. When I acquire and clear resources, I do it with `withResource` Tasty's function:

```
withResource :: IO a -> (a -> IO ()) -> (IO a -> TestTree) -> TestTree
```

where `a` is type of resource. But I want to keep resources if tests fail and to clear them only if tests passed. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test failures (at least in `tasty-hunit`) are [implemented as exceptions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-hunit-0.10.0.1/docs/Test-Tasty-HUnit.html#t:Assertion).  The purpose of `withResource` and [`bracket`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket) is to free resources even when there is an exception.  If you write straight-line code like this, the resource will be freed if and only if the assertions pass:

```
testCase "resource management" $ do
    a <- allocate
    assertBool =<< runTest
    cleanUp a
```

Comment: but no way to do it in cleanup function which is passing to withResource as 2nd argument due to no way to get Result (status) there?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but you could use an [AllSucceed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-1.3.1/docs/Test-Tasty.html#g:6) dependency and define a dummy test that would clean up your resource but would run only in the case when certain other tests succeed.

A caveat is that such a cleanup test could be filtered out by a pattern.

Alternatively, I think I'd accept a pull request that adds a version of withResource with an additional `Outcome` argument.